# Wind speed in a building, windows and angles as factors: is ANOVA appropriate?

Tags: r, anova

EDIT

Is an ANOVA appropriate for rhe following?

I have a physical cuboidal building in an open field with a single window (S) or 2 windows (X).

[image]

**1. Single window cube (S)** : I measure a variable (air speed) at 10,000 points inside this cube (blue plane) and compute the average. I then turn the cube a few degrees with respect to the oncoming wind (angle) and repeat the experiment.

**2. 2 window cube (X):** Repeat with same angles.

I'd like to know if there is a way of identifying which factor (angle or window set-up) is more important for varying the air speed inside?

I now have a table of values:

```
z= speed angle window
    15 0 S
    20 0 S
    25 0 X
    04 0 X
    55 15 S
    16 15 S
    15 15 X
    20 15 X
```

...

In R then I do:

```
ACH.aova <- aov(speed~ window*angle, data=z)
summary(ACH.aova)
TukeyHSD(ACH.aova)
plot(TukeyHSD(ACH.aova, "angle"))
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best method or how to interpret the results... Any help would be much appreciated,

Comment: Did you specify to R that window and angle are categorical variables? That is the first step; i.e. do the following two commands before your "ACH.aova" : angle <- as.factor(angle)    and     window <- as.factor(window). This is important for the angle variable because your setup regards it as a numerical variable at the moment which is not correct.

Comment: Ahh yes of course, thank you! What would you say is the best way to present/plot the relationship or significance?

Comment: I've just realised my air speeds on the blue plane are not normally distributed... This is a problem for ANOVA isn't it? I guess I am looking for a two way factorial test for non normal output variable. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm not sure if this is the best method or how to interpret the results... Any help would be much appreciated,

On interpreting results: Please specify if there is something in particular you are unsure of. When it comes to ANOVA: The F-value describes whether the variation between groups is the same as within groups. E.g.:

Where the null hypothesis states:
H0 = the two groups are equal

And the Alternative hypothesis states:
HA = the two groups are not equal

If the null hypothesis (H0=the two groups are equal) is true, than F should be near 1, deviating from it only by chance. The P-value is the probability that the variation seen between the groups is due to chance.

Whether this is the best method: See below.

> I've just realised my air speeds on the blue plane are not normally distributed... This is a problem for ANOVA isn't it? I guess I am looking for a two way factorial test for non normal output variable. What do you think?

If your data was normally distributed, you could have run a paired T-test. Since you have too little data to assume a normal distribution, and your data doesn't follow a normal distribution, you need to use a non-parametric (does not require a normal distribution) method. Also, the F-test is highly sensitive to non-normality. The Mann-Whitney U test is a non-parametric alternative to t-test or ANOVA for two groups.

Here is a page from Quick-R with non-parametric testing of group diffferences:

http://www.statmethods.net/stats/nonparametric.html

Comment: Thank you for this. I have 10,000 air speed measurements inside the building but I can see from a histogram that they are not normally distributed. Ideally I'd like to draw conclusions from whether there is a relationship between angle and speed (linear model perhaps?) or S/X and speed? This I'm reasonably comfortable with.  Additionally is there an optimum set-up of angle and S/X that increases speed for example? This latter is where I'm not so comfortable... What do you think the best approach should b?

Comment: Using the 10 000 measurements that you have is ideal. 
Just looking at a histogram is a very subjective way of identifying non-normality. Have you tried running normality tests, or a QQ plot to check for normality?

You can try log-scaling your dependent variable (wind-speed) and see if that causes it to be normally distributed. If this works, you can run a glm and test for the effect of angle and window on windspeed, and simultaneously test for group differences.